# Problems accessing Drupal 6 menu_router URL paths

Tags: routes, uri

This week I started to support an existing Drupal 6.19 website with an Ubercart store and some other original content. I have tried for two days now to set up and enable modules such as core's update, contrib devel and a couple of the ubercart extra modules with limited success. Through a node running PHP debugging code, I have been able to check that the various permissions are indeed set and that some of the functions in each module can be called successfully.

However, none of the expected menu router entries are appearing. As a result, none of the URLs defined in `hook_menu()` functions of each of these modules are accessible. They all return 'Page Not Found'.

There has to be something wrong with the {menu_router} table contents, but I am at a loss on how to further debug this problem.  I have manually and via code cleared the menu cache as well as called `menu_rebuild()`. However, there has been no visible progress.

Do you have any idea or suggestion on how to resolve this, or how to further proceed in debugging this vexing issue?

Comment: You need to either step with a debugger or check what menu_get_items reads from the table, then add debug statements to _menu_translate().